# How to add persistent IP address in powershell

Tags: powershell

Why can I successfully add an IP address with this command

```
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.168 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 34
```

but the same command fails for persistent address

```
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.168 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 34 -PolicyStore PersistentStore

New-NetIPAddress : Invalid parameter PolicyStore PersistentStore
At line:1 char:1
+ New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.168 -PrefixLength 24 -Interface ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress) [New-NetIPAddress], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,New-NetIPAddress
```

Running in PowerShell 5.1 as Administrator.

Comment: It is complaining that the parameter `PolicyStore PersistentStore` is invalid for the WMI object 'MSFT_NetIPAddress' 'Store' property during creation. Is there a reason you are specifying this? According to the documentation "*If you do not specify this parameter, the default entries are created in both the ActiveStore and the PersistentStore.*" Also note that the default behavior of the MSFT_NetIPAddress class is to create persistent objects, and the documentation is "TBD" - not a good sign.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh872425(v=vs.85)

Comment: Well, Greg, if it's already persistent then I suggest you to post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct one. It's really strange New-NetIPAddress command does not accept the argument listed in its documentation.

Comment: You may want to specify if the command that does not produce an error does not produce the desired results. It isn't clear from the question and comments. Also, there is a *lot* of WMI network stuff that either is not implemented, or just doesn't work. Part of knowing the Windows ecosystem landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg Askew explained in the comments, PolicyStore is irrelevant for New-NetIPAddress command even though it's an officially documented command argument.

This command

```
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.168 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 34
```

creates persistent IP address anyways.